# Delete/pull one document based on multiple conditions

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to find one MongoDB document based on two inputs from the user. Here's my example:

```
public async Task RemoveAdminRole(string userId, string groupId) { 
    var idFilter = Builders<Group>.Filter.Eq(group => group._id, groupId);
    var roleFilter = Builders<Group>.Update.PullFilter(group => group.Roles, role => role.UserId == userId);
    var roleFilter2 = Builders<Group>.Update.PullFilter(group => group.Roles, role => role.Role == "ADMIN");

    var update = roleFilter & roleFilter2;

    await this.DataContext.MongoCollection.UpdateOneAsync(idFilter, update);
}
```

Basically what I want to do there, is remove/pull the element "Roles" inside `Group` that has `role.Role == "ADMIN"` and `role.UserId == userId`. I'm getting an error:

> Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UpdateDefinition<Group>' and 'UpdateDefinition<Group>'

How would I create multiple of these `PullFilter` (or similar) so I can remove the specific element based on my two inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the second one like follows:

```
var roleFilter = Builders<Group>.Update
    .PullFilter(group => group.Roles, role => role.UserId == userId)
    .PullFilter(group => group.Roles, role => role.Role == "ADMIN");
```

Comment: Damn, I didn't even know you could just do that. Thanks! On another note, have you ever had an account on a forum called HF? Just curious.

Comment: No, this is my only account.

Comment: Alright, just knew a guy by that name. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Hmm, for some reason this removes ALL with the `role.Role == "ADMIN"` and totally ignores the `role.UserId == userId`. I want both conditions to be true.

Comment: Why not use and && inside the filter? role => role.Role == "ADMIN" && role.UserId == userId...

Comment: I cannot test it now but does it make any difference if you swap the two PullFilters?

Comment: @CraigWilson Thanks a lot, that did it. I didn't know you could put many conditions inside a pull filter. Oh well, that's pretty neat.